# How can I sort a HashMap<String, Pair<Double, Integer>> by Double Value?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, java-stream

How can I sort a `HashMap<String, Pair<Double, Integer>> myMap` by the value in the Double parameter using Stream?

Comment: Did you try anything? Please show us your code.

Comment: The short answer, you can't sort an HashMap because it doesn't retain any trace of order.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic for not trying to attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `sorted` method with the below comparator and collect to a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Map<String, Pair<Double, Integer>> result = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.getValue().getKey()))
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (l, r) -> l,
                        LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Note that `toMap` is `Collectors.toMap` if you're not statically importing the `toMap` method.

Comment: @nullpointer if you want to close a question, delete or whatever, do so with your privileges. I have nothing else to say.